# MongoDB Lookup with Conditions

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, lookup

Sorry for what I'm sure is a newbie question but after a couple dais I'm at a total loss on how to approach this.

I've currently two collections, one being `orders` and another one being `offers`. Offers are basically quote offers to the orders (linked by `_id<->orderId`).

Example of Orders collection:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59311d8ba0ea6500113df5d6"), 
    "deleted" : true, 
    "updated" : ISODate("2017-06-02T08:20:47.772+0000"), 
    "created" : ISODate("2017-06-02T08:10:51.401+0000"), 
    "name" : "Sicherungsbolzen",
    "state" : "active"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59311ee2a0ea6500113df5d8"), 
    "deleted" : false, 
    "updated" : ISODate("2017-06-02T08:16:34.911+0000"), 
    "created" : ISODate("2017-06-02T08:16:34.911+0000"), 
    "name" : "Mitnehmerstein SK50 ",
    "state" : "active"
}
```

Example of Quotes collection:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59311ee2a0ea6500113df5d8"), 
    "deleted" : false, 
    "updated" : ISODate("2019-11-08T13:18:34.872+0000"), 
    "created" : ISODate("2019-11-08T06:54:14.072+0000"), 
    "orderId" : ObjectId("5db6c679d8499800286ff64a"), 
    "proposal" : {
        "price" : NumberInt(19800), 
        "currency" : "CUR51", 
        "deliveryDate" : NumberInt(21), 
        "files" : [

        ]
    }, 
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59311d8ba0ea6500113df5d6"), 
    "deleted" : false, 
    "updated" : ISODate("2019-11-08T10:11:48.112+0000"), 
    "created" : ISODate("2019-10-29T11:31:05.980+0000"), 
    "orderId" : ObjectId("5db74034d849980028701a95"), 
    "proposal" : {
        "price" : 31.78, 
        "currency" : "CUR48", 
        "deliveryDate" : NumberInt(1), 
        "files" : [

        ]
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59311d8ba0ea6500113df5d6"), 
    "deleted" : false, 
    "updated" : ISODate("2019-11-08T08:37:04.354+0000"), 
    "created" : ISODate("2019-11-08T08:37:04.354+0000"), 
    "orderId" : ObjectId("5db80b84ed142100263a5088"), 
    "proposal" : {
        "price" : NumberInt(2345), 
        "deliveryDate" : NumberInt(18), 
        "currency" : "CUR48", 
        "files" : [

        ]
    }, 
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59311d8ba0ea6500113df5d6"), 
    "deleted" : false, 
    "updated" : ISODate("2019-11-15T14:32:15.958+0000"), 
    "created" : ISODate("2019-11-06T14:42:23.492+0000"), 
    "orderId" : ObjectId("5dc03382751ecc002899e1fa"), 
    "proposal" : {
        "price" : NumberInt(86400), 
        "currency" : "CUR48", 
        "deliveryDate" : NumberInt(90), 
        "files" : [

        ]
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59311d8ba0ea6500113df5d6"), 
    "deleted" : false, 
    "updated" : ISODate("2019-11-22T23:10:07.056+0000"), 
    "created" : ISODate("2019-11-06T20:09:20.706+0000"), 
    "orderId" : ObjectId("5dc03382751ecc002899e1fa"), 
    "proposal" : {
        "price" : NumberInt(57419), 
        "currency" : "CUR48", 
        "deliveryDate" : NumberInt(27), 
        "files" : [

        ]
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59311d8ba0ea6500113df5d6"), 
    "deleted" : false, 
    "updated" : ISODate("2019-11-08T08:52:18.910+0000"), 
    "created" : ISODate("2019-11-08T08:52:18.910+0000"), 
    "orderId" : ObjectId("5dc05c0a751ecc00289a0187"), 
    "proposal" : {
        "price" : NumberInt(9900), 
        "deliveryDate" : NumberInt(35), 
        "currency" : "CUR48", 
        "files" : [

        ]
    }, 
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59311d8ba0ea6500113df5d6"), 
    "deleted" : false, 
    "updated" : ISODate("2019-11-08T09:39:12.383+0000"), 
    "created" : ISODate("2019-11-08T09:39:12.383+0000"), 
    "orderId" : ObjectId("5dc47fb10a1f7c00262763e3"), 
    "proposal" : {
        "price" : NumberInt(79), 
        "deliveryDate" : NumberInt(7), 
        "currency" : "CUR48", 
        "files" : [

        ]
    }, 
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59311ee2a0ea6500113df5d8"), 
    "deleted" : false, 
    "updated" : ISODate("2019-11-08T09:45:41.392+0000"), 
    "created" : ISODate("2019-11-08T09:45:41.392+0000"), 
    "orderId" : ObjectId("5dc480ab751ecc00289b32c7"), 
    "proposal" : {
        "price" : NumberInt(240), 
        "deliveryDate" : NumberInt(7), 
        "currency" : "CUR48", 
        "message" : "Hi Alex, I saw you put several RFQs in the platform,attached quotation for reference.If you have any question,please contact me at engineer07@top-rp.cn. Looking forward to your feedback.By the way,may I know your email?\n\nRebecca", 
        "files" : [

        ]
    }, 
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59311ee2a0ea6500113df5d8"), 
    "deleted" : false, 
    "updated" : ISODate("2019-11-08T09:43:29.928+0000"), 
    "created" : ISODate("2019-11-08T09:43:29.928+0000"), 
    "orderId" : ObjectId("5dc482430a1f7c00262763e6"), 
    "proposal" : {
        "price" : NumberInt(390), 
        "deliveryDate" : NumberInt(7), 
        "currency" : "CUR48", 
        "message" : "Hi Alex, I saw you put several RFQs in the platform,attached quotation for reference.If you have any question,please contact me at engineer07@top-rp.cn. Looking forward to your feedback.By the way,may I know your email?\n\nRebecca", 
        "files" : [

        ]
    }, 
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59311ee2a0ea6500113df5d8"), 
    "deleted" : false, 
    "updated" : ISODate("2019-11-08T06:56:15.346+0000"), 
    "created" : ISODate("2019-11-08T06:56:15.346+0000"), 
    "orderId" : ObjectId("5dc4843b0a1f7c00262763ed"), 
    "proposal" : {
        "price" : NumberInt(3), 
        "deliveryDate" : NumberInt(7), 
        "currency" : "CUR48", 
        "files" : [

        ]
    }, 
}
```

**I've a main goal:**
Export an excel that will display the "average" of prices per quote. That is, if an order received 3 quotes (20, 30, 40) it will be: OrderID, 30 (being 30 the average of 20, 30, 40).

In this case, having 2 orders (59311d8ba0ea6500113df5d6 and 59311ee2a0ea6500113df5d8), it must display:

```
ORDERID, AVERAGE OF PRICE

59311ee2a0ea6500113df5d8, 99 (average all the proposal.price for each quote of this order)
59311d8ba0ea6500113df5d6, 129 (average all the proposal.price for each quote of this order)
```

Any hints, tips, help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Provide please sample data and expected results in both cases

Comment: Is `being 90 the average of 20, 30, 40` a typo or did you mean `sum`?

Comment: It's indeed a typo sorry. Correcting it now.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a job for the new [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries)

```
db.Orders.aggregate([
 {$project:{_id:1}),
 {$lookup: {
     from: "Quotes",
     let: {order:"$_id"},
     pipeline: [
        {$match: {$expr: {$eq:["$orderId","$$order"]}}},
        {$group: {_id:null, average:{$avg:"$proposal.price"}}}
     ],
     as: "quotes"
 }}
])
```

This should return documents like

```
{_id: ObjectId("..."),
quotes:[{_id:null, average:xxx}]}
```